# How should I split up Rust modules so that they match corresponding C++ namespaces?

Tags: c++, rust

I'm trying to write a code generation tool that generates Rust wrapper functions for C++ code similar to bindgen.  I'm facing a problem mapping C++ namespaces to Rust modules.

I have a frontend that spits out a number of C++ functions defined in (potentially) different namespaces and I want to create matching Rust wrapper functions. I can't "split" modules across one or multiple files the way I could in C++:

```rust
pub mod foo {
   // some function definitions
}

pub mod bar {
   // some function definitions
}

pub mod foo {
   // doesn't work!
}
```

I also cannot re-export private function declarations within a module:

```rust
fn func1() { /* ... */ }
fn func2() { /* ... */ }

pub mod foo {
    // not valid either!
    pub use super::func1;
    pub use super::func2;
}
```

What else can I do here? An obvious solution would be to first collect all functions defined in some C++ namespace and then output wrapper functions for all of them once inside a corresponding module but I would prefer to process them in the order in which they appear in the original C++ source code.

Comment: Why the close votes? I know this probably isn't good practice but this is a (valid?) niche use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to be able to reexport a function definition is for it to be (1) visible to the reexporting module and (2) marked `pub`. In particular, its containing module does *not* need to be marked `pub`. That means you can do this:

```
mod bindings_impl {
    pub fn func1() { /* ... */ }
    pub fn func2() { /* ... */ }
}
    
pub mod foo {
    pub use super::bindings_impl::func1;
    pub use super::bindings_impl::func2;
}
```

And `func1` and `func2` will be accessible from `foo` while `bindings_impl` remains private.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to 'split up' a module as in C++, you can use the `include!` macro. Its use is generally discouraged in handwritten code, but for bindings/generated code it may be more acceptable. Something like this should do the trick:

In `foo.rs`:

```
include!("./foo_funcs_1.rs");
include!("./foo_funcs_2.rs");
/* and so on... */
```

In `foo_funcs_1.rs`:

```
pub fn func1() { /* ... */ }
// other function definitions...
```

In `foo_funcs_2.rs`:

```
pub fn func2() { /* ... */ }
// other function definitions...
```

However, `include!` really just dumps the textual contents of the files it's passed into the invocation site,  which means you can run into issues with repeated names. In particular, if you tried to `use` the same item in both `foo_funcs_1.rs` and `foo_funcs_2.rs` you'd get an error because you're trying to import the same item twice in the same scope. This could be somewhat of a headache to deal with.